# VBA Run-time error '1004': Paste method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel

At first this code was "sort of working", meaning that it would paste the information to the destination but not in the correct cells, and adding additional rows instead of skipping empty rows. Once I got it to paste correctly to the appropriate cells it no longer wants to work.

I'm sure this a fairly simple issue but I'm at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Myfile As String
Dim erowFilepath = ("C:\Users\YOU DONT NEED TO SEE THIS PART\Desktop\LINKED TRACKERS\")
Myfile = Dir("C:\Users\OR THIS PART\Desktop\LINKED TRACKERS\")

Do While Len(Myfile) > 0
    If Myfile = "COMPANY_CYCLE.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & Myfile)
    Worksheets("ROSTER").Range("A3:O3").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ' ***The line below is the line I get an error***
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("MANNINGROSTER").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

    Myfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Long story short: I'm attempting to consolidate data from 4 different workbooks that users will input data, to a single workbook that I can monitor and process information as it is put in day by day.

I'm fairly certain that the issue is stemming from the source worksheets being password protected and that the paste destination is the same for all 4 workbooks as well.

I can,t seem to figure out a way to correct this.  One error leads to another, and another, etc.

Comment: Few things needs to be corrected, Declaration erowFilepath, change to `Dim erowFilepath : erowFilepath = (C:\Users\YOU DONT NEED TO SEE THIS PART\Desktop\LINKED TRACKERS\)` Also don't use ActiveWorkbook instead create  a workbook object an perform operation.

Comment: Ive previously tried that.  Started getting Run-Time error '1004: Sorry, we couldn't find "designated file name.xlsm". Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted.

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be at the top of every one of your code modules

Comment: Also, make sure to let VBA know what sheet you want `Rows.Count` to be on. For example, it should be `erow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` if you want to count the rows on Sheet2.  Same thing when using `Cells()`. Be sure to put the worksheet those are to be on before it.

Comment: I just realized I was changing the declaration and forgetting to change    (Filepath & Myfile)  to     (erowFilepath & Myfile)   unfortunately I'm still getting the same Paste Error message after making the correction

Comment: You are exiting the sub as soon as you reach the file "COMPANY_CYCLE.xlsm" - do all your other files have alphabetically lower names than that?

Comment: Seems like erow and FilePath should be two distinct variables? Posted code needs fixing.

Comment: You need to fully qualify `Cells` in the `Paste` line.  They're on the `ActiveSheet`, not `Worksheets("MANNINGROSTER")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Myfile As String, Filepath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, rng As Range

    Myfile = Dir("C:\Users\OR THIS PART\Desktop\LINKED TRACKERS\")
    Filepath = ("C:\Users\YOU DONT NEED TO SEE THIS PART\Desktop\LINKED TRACKERS\")

    Do While Len(Myfile) > 0

        If Myfile Like "*.xls*" And UCase(Myfile) <> "COMPANY_CYCLE.XLSM" Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & Myfile)
            Set rng = wb.Worksheets("ROSTER").Range("A3:O3")

            'EDIT: copy values only, (when there's something to copy)
            If Application.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
                With Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
                End With
            End If
            'Note: if there's nothing in ColA for the copied range, this will
            '  throw off the next copy and you may end up overwriting data...

            wb.Close False

        End If
        Myfile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you!.  Now I just need to tweak it so that it only pastes cell values vs. formatting, empty rows etc.  

Much appreciated!

Comment: So I've been messing with this for a couple days now and still haven't found a way to only past the value of the cells being copied. 

I'm teaching myself to use VBA and I'm rapidly running out of Copenhagen, Monster, and the desire to do this anymore lol.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot. I previously attempted a near identical script minus the     Value= RNG.value. For some reason I put value=cell.value (which would explain the error message I received).